# Why firebase database now returns null when used to work great?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase web App that used to read and write a firebase database just fine. But as of this week the same code:

```
var ref = new Firebase ('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/web/data');
ref.child(ID + "/slot" + timeSlot + "/vote").on("value",function(snapshot){
console.log(snapshot.val()); // this is now returning null
sVal = (snapshot.val());
```

now  returns `null` for `sVal`.

Can anyone please explain 1.why and 2.what I should do about it? Thank you.

Comment: This sounds like a very specific troubleshooting issue, you should try contacting them: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Well... or the values of `ID` or `timeSlot` changed to now point to an empty location in the database.